# How to prevent input type="date" from changing the date order

Tags: html, forms, date

> This is my first question ever asked here at Stackoverflow and my
>   English isn't any good, so please don't be too hard on me. ;)

I'm living in the Netherlands and here we note dates as *DD-MM-YYYY*, but when I use input type="date" it turns the date around to *YYYY-MM-DD*. Is there any solution to prevent this from happening?

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Not possible. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: This was helpful. Thankyou @pokeybit

Comment: Sorry but this is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format